# What is the differences in rendering in asp.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What is the differences in operators for render server code?

```
Operator: <%@
Operator: <%:
Operator: <%=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%: html-encodes the result
<%= is equal to Response.Write
<%@ is an preprocessor derictive

Answer (score 9):

`<%=` simply evaluates an expression and writes the result to the page output

`<%:` is the same, but also HTML encodes the output - unless the output implements IHtmlString

`<%@` is for special framework directives, e.g. <%@ Page for specifying page attributes such as the master page

`<%` is for code blocks that are statements, not expressions. These will not generate page output unless you explicitly call a function that writes to the output.

`<%#` is for data-binding expressions, which are evaluated when a webforms control is databound. They are therefore rarely used in MVC.

Comment: <%: is the same, but also HTML encodes the output - unless the output implements IHtmlString

Comment: <%if (true){ %>
                <%=Resources.GlobalResources.Not_Available%>
                <%   }
                  else
                  {%>
                <%= Model.NextAppointmentDate%>
                <%  }%>  i want to write it only with code

Comment: i want with one block of <% C# code   %> to  write in view(aspx)

Comment: for example: <%if (true){ Html.Write(Resources.GlobalResources.Not_Available)} else {Html.Write( Model.NextAppointmentDate) }%>